# storing listview position in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a ListView item in my application. The scroll position does not get restored properly when coming back from another activity if the top item was partially visible. Is there any way to maintain the previous position as it is?

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To store it:

```
listView.getLastVisiblePosition()
```

To restore it:

```
listView.setSelection(...)
```